# How can I write DSL in python when I want to query multiple "must_not"?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to  query multiple "must_not" like this:

```
{
"query":{
    "bool": {
        "must": { "regexp":   { "DstIP": "192.168.81.*" }},
        "should": [
            { "bool": {
                "must_not":  { "regexp": { "sourceIP": "192.168.*" }},
                "must_not":  { "regexp": { "sourceIP": "10.[0-255]." }},
            }}
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
}}
```

This means that I want to query DstIP  is 192.168.81.0-255 but except for sourceIP 192.168.* and 10.* .

But  the dictionary  uses unique key in python so this code result is:

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': {'regexp': {'ciscoDstIP': '192.168.81.*'}},
   'should': [{'bool': {'must_not': {'regexp': {'ciscoSrcIP': '10.[0-255].'}}}}],
   'minimum_should_match': 1}}}
```

How can I change my DSL code to query  multiple "must_not" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "regexp": {
          "DstIP": "192.168.81.*"
        }
      },
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "sourceIP": "192.168.*"
                }
              },
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "sourceIP": "10.[0-255].*"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```